# Load list of Users in two Azure Active Directory Groups using Graph API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I am extremely new to Active Directory and to Azure, as will likely be obvious from my question. I am using the [MVC Directory Graph Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Write-Sample-App-for-79e55502) as a reference. I am able to do most of the things that I am attempting but I ran into a problem:

I have a hierarchy of Groups and Users in Azure Active Directory where I have two levels of groups (e.g. GroupA contains GroupB and GroupC, GroupD contains GroupE...). Users can be in, theoretically, any combination of these groups (e.g. GroupA, GroupD and GroupE).

I pass two strings to my MVC project controller where each string is the ID of a Group in my Azure Active Directory. I want to load only the User objects that overlap in the two Groups, i.e. only the Users that are in both groups.

Following along with one of the example projects from MSDN, I am able to load a list of all of the users in one of the Groups like so:

```
Group groupA = DirectoryService.groups.Where(it => (it.objectId == GroupAId)).SingleOrDefault();
DirectoryService.LoadProperty(groupA , "members");
List<User> usersListA = groupA.members.OfType<User>().ToList();
```

Duplicating this for the second list, I can then intersect the two:

```
Group groupB = DirectoryService.groups.Where(it => (it.objectId == GroupBId)).SingleOrDefault();
DirectoryService.LoadProperty(groupB , "members");
List<User> usersListB = groupA.members.OfType<User>().ToList();

List<User> finalList = usersListA.Intersect(usersListB);
```

Basically, I'm loading both lists fully... my question is - is there a better way to do this?

For example, after I've loaded the list of Users from GroupA, is there a way for me to filter the list to include only those who belong to GroupB? Something along the lines of:

```
//<Incorrect syntax>
List<User> finalList =  groupA.Where(user => user.memberOf("GroupB"));
//</Incorrect syntax>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to do this server-side, if that's what you are looking for.